# How to add a 3 second delay in C#?

Tags: c#, delay

I just started in coding c#, and I am making a Bot for my discord server. I recently added a command !meme, where it would randomly pull from around 100 different pictures to send in the chat. The second I implemented this command, everyone just totally abused it, and it was at the point where there was like 15 pictures popping up in chat every 2 seconds because of the !meme spam.

I want to be able to add a 3 second delay before the command itself can be used again. I tried using `Thread.Sleep(3000);` and that did not work. Same for 
await `Task.Delay(3000);` which I used inside of the async.

```
       private void RegisterMemeCommand()
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("Meme")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                int RandomMeme = rng.Next(MemeList.Length);
                string memetopost = MemeList[RandomMeme];
                await e.Channel.SendFile(memetopost);
            });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by it did not work?

Comment: Yes I had that, didn't paste it in completely.

Comment: Record the last time the command was used. When someone uses it again, compare the current time to that time. If it's not more than three seconds greater, *don't execute the command*.

Comment: It didn't work as in just nothing happened. There was no error, just didn't have a cooldown and people could keep spamming.

Comment: @EricLippert Could you like type that out? Because I do not know how to take the current time, or to have a if this amount of time didn't pass by, then dont execute

Comment: @JohnLandon DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
 Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")); Just add the .Now before the call and after the call and get the difference.

Comment: Timer and Boolean flag indicating if the timer has elapsed since the last call? You could even use the status of the timer as the flag.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, I honestly don't know how I could add a DateTime.Now twice before and after the same command. I edited the post and added the code I need with a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have complete code, from what you have up in the question, try this:

```
var lastSentOn=DateTime.MinValue;
commands.CreateCommand("Meme")
.Do(async (e) =>
{
    if((DateTime.Now - lastSentOn).TotalSeconds > 3)
    { 
        int RandomMeme = rng.Next(MemeList.Length);
        string memetopost = MemeList[RandomMeme];
        lastSentOn = DateTime.Now;
        await e.Channel.SendFile(memetopost);
    }
});
```

You may need to associate `lastSentOn` with some user id etc. A dictionary will be helpful in this scenario.

Comment: thanks @mike z, for putting more appropriate property.

Comment: It gave me a bunch of errors. I edited my post to add a bit more of the code, not sure if it will change anything. Says the time lacks the await operator, says that "time" does not exist in the current context and says that the ToString lacks an await operator. Also, my await which was working before now says it can only be used with an async method.

Comment: @JohnLandon OK, so remove that line. I already did it in this answer. The use of `time` was only there because you included it in the question.

Comment: thanks @mikez for correcting. I got stuck in a meeting :(